# Hadoop Mongo integration

Tags: mongodb, hadoop

I tried to integrate Hadoop MongoDB, followed https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/hadoop/#installation, but i didn't understand the process. Can anyone help me out how to integrate mongo and hadoop